# Integrating Inventory using Squareup and Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress

Scratching my head for over a week. Here is why... 
Now that there are Inventory Management programs for [Square](https://squareup.com/) users,I've been trying to solve this; how to integrate Brick and mortar with ecommerce.

Scenario
- Use Squareup at Store
- Use Woocommerce 
- balance inventory from one source.

Tradegecko integrates with Woocommerce.
[Otterology](http://otterology.com) and [shopventory][3] integrates with Squareup.

Is there a way I could have just 1 of these (TG, Otter, or Shopv) as my inventory management software for both square and woocommerce?  I'd like to stay away from Quickbooks at all cost.  I'm willing to get creative, perhaps use another software.  Any and all information and ideas as welcome and most most most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I heard that Otterology will be supporting woo commerce soon, but I'm not sure about the timeline. You should be able to find updates in their blog section at https://otterology.com if you're still interested in that functionality. Otherwise, you could check out ShopKeep which offers a complete online and physical store solution; but you'd need to switch from woo commerce.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on the same... Scratching my head comparing and testing...for two weeks and going on...

- one answer could be:
  Maybe Veeqo?
  Although i like better TradeGecko, Veeqo (wich is soooo slowly updating importations!) offers a POS too (not cheap).
  Anyone finding solutions to that?
- another idea i had:
  Using TradeGecko as a POS, i mean creating Orders directly. Then you don't have a POS with thumbnails and all that nice screen, but anyway you are able to create oders, bill them, manege stock and sync with woo, and that's it.
- Forgetting about Square and using one of the two POS plugins that actually exist for Woocomerce:

  1. http://woopos.com.au/
  2. http://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-point-of-sale-pos/7869665
- StitchLab does integrate with both Woocomerce and Square, but not quite good as TradeGecko in inventory management i think.